# How can I use Twitter Bootstrap's tags in my php script

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap commands in my PHP script but it doesn't work , in the same sense whenever i use html tags , it works properly . The problem is that Bootstrap classes are not working in php script . Can Anybody help me , How can I use Bootstraps classes in my php script just as HTML Tags .

Comment: You should provide an example and explain errors in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem using Twitter Bootstrap classes and commands in PHP. PHP just renders code before it renders in the visitors web browser. So if you have problems with classes working as they should there must be something wrong with the code.

If you could please post the code you are having troubles with it would be much easier to help you, as there is no correct answer to your question as it is right now.